# Find records where two values are the same and one is not

Tags: mysql

[TABLE SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYGNT.jpg)

From the table shown, I need a result set that shows those two records based on the EMAIL values being different. Getting a count of records to match in LAST_NAME and FIRST_NAME and EMAIL > 1 is not difficult.

The difficulty is in how to show both records in the result set.

I have been trying all kinds of combinations with HAVING, JOINS, PARTITIONS and so far I have not been able to hit the right SQL statement.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Finally, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you spend the time to take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways you can achieve this. Here are two:

```
SELECT *
FROM sample
WHERE (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME) IN (
    SELECT LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
    FROM sample
    GROUP BY LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME) cnt
    FROM sample
) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```